# Linux block device module is hanging when unloading with rmmod (del_gendisk)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a little example for block device drivers in Linux. This example is not complete and I take progress step by step. I registered a block device with `blkdev_register` and allocated the gendisk structure with `alloc_disk`. All works fine, when inserting the module. It shows up in */proc/devices*. But if I want to unload it with `rmmod`, it hangs.

I figured out, that in the module unload function, the call to `del_gendisk` caused the hanging. I know that the gendisk structure has an embedded kobject, which takes care of reference counting. This mechanism hinders you to unload the module, while it's being used. But since I don't call `add_disk`, there should be no reference's to that structure.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/genhd.h>
#include <linux/blkdev.h>

#define BLKDEVNAME  "blkdev_test"
#define MINORS      16  

struct block_device_operations bdops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE
};

struct blkdev {
    int major;  
    struct gendisk *disk;
    struct request_queue *queue;
} dev;


static int __init blkdev_init(void)         
{                                                                   
    dev.major = register_blkdev( 0, BLKDEVNAME );   
    if( dev.major < 0 )
        return -EIO;

    dev.disk = alloc_disk(MINORS);
    if( dev.disk == NULL )
        goto DISK_ERR;

    dev.disk->major = dev.major;
    dev.disk->first_minor = 0;
    snprintf(dev.disk->disk_name, DISK_NAME_LEN, "bd0" ); 
    dev.disk->fops = &bdops;
    // dev.disk->queue = dev.queue;

    // add_disk( dev.disk );

    return 0;

DISK_ERR:
    unregister_blkdev( dev.major, BLKDEVNAME ); 
    return -EIO;
}

static void __exit blkdev_exit(void) 
{
    del_gendisk(dev.disk);  
    unregister_blkdev( dev.major, BLKDEVNAME );
}

module_init(blkdev_init);   
module_exit(blkdev_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

If I issue the command `sudo rmmod mod.ko` then the command gets killed by the system.

Comment: And why did you comment out `add_disk()`?

Comment: What happens when you comment out `del_gendisk(dev.disk);` (since you also commented out add_disk()).  May I refer you (probably redundantly) to https://lwn.net/Articles/25711/.

Comment: A simple example is also given here: https://lwn.net/Articles/58720/ .

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting](https://lwn.net/Articles/25711/) :

> Manipulating gendisks Once you have your gendisk structure set up, you
>   have to add it to the list of active disks; that is done with:
>
> ```
> void add_disk(struct gendisk *disk);
> ```
>
> After this call, your device is active. There are a few things worth
>   keeping in mind about add_disk():
>
> ```
> add_disk() can create I/O to the device (to read partition tables and such). You should not call add_disk() until your driver is
> sufficiently initialized to handle requests.
>
> If you are calling add_disk() in your driver initialization routine, you should not fail the initialization process after the
> first call.
>
> The call to add_disk() increments the disk's reference count; if the disk structure is ever to be released, the driver is responsible
> for decrementing that count (with put_disk()).
> ```
>
> Should you need to remove a disk from the system, that is accomplished
>   with:
>
> ```
> void del_gendisk(struct gendisk *disk);
> ```
>
> This function cleans up all of the information associated with the
>   given disk, and generally removes it from the system. After a call to
>   del_gendisk(), no more operations will be sent to the given device.
>   Your driver's reference to the gendisk object remains, though; you
>   must explicitly release it with:
>
> ```
> void put_disk(struct gendisk *disk);
> ```
>
> That call will cause the gendisk structure to be freed, as long as no
>   other part of the kernel retains a reference to it.

Comment: Still hanging. My first comment was a mistake, i forget to insert and remove the module.